# Using a for loop inside ionic app works on linux but not on ios

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework

I have made an app using ionic. 
Inside it, I make a `http get` to get some value from my db. 
Then, I loop through the result to compute the difference in terms of time between the created date of my value inside the db and the actual date.

This code works very well on my linux but when I run the code on my iphone on ios, everything works fine except the for loop which does not work... it's very strange. Someone faced it ?

```
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    let date = new Date();
    this.http.get(this.server + `json.php?&id=${1}`).subscribe(resData => {
      console.log(resData);
      this.events = resData;

      for (let i=0; i < 10; i++){
        this.events[i]['unique_id'] = parseInt(this.events[i]['unique_id']);
        if ((date.getTime() - new Date(this.events[i].created_at).getTime()) / 1000 < 60) {
          this.events[i].ecart_now = 'there is ' + Math.round((date.getTime() - new Date(this.events[i].created_at).getTime()) / 1000)  + 's';
        }
      }
    })

  }
```

Comment: Judging from the code, you're trying to concatenate strings with number. Try `'there is ' + String(Math.round((date.getTime() - new Date(this.events[i].created_at).getTime()) / 1000)) + 's';`. Not sure if this is the source of the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by: it doesnt work? Are you getting an error or an unexpected result?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelD, good point, but still not working...

Comment: @ukn no error, it's just that when I tried to console log this.events, I have all value from my db, but 'ecart_now' that I compute is not inside : this.events,,, it's on linux but not on ios ...

Comment: @Yann92 So you dont know if the for is executed or not since you have a condition. Could it be that the operation priority(in the if) is different which would be weird but thats the only reason I can see the assignation be avoided. Try addind parenthesis around: (date.getTime() - new Date(this.events[i].created_at).getTime()) / 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A high possibility is the invalid date format. Safari and Internet Explorer browsers have issue with date format: `new Date("2011-02-07");`.

Console log `new Date(this.events[i].created_at)` and you would see invalid date.

Use below formats:

```
new Date(2011, 01, 07);
new Date(2011, 01, 07, 11, 05, 00);
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! This was the solution, it works perfectly